# count of occurences group by customers every 4 hours

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows:

```
id  email   Date of purchase    time of purchase
1   abc@gmail.com   11/10/18    12:10 PM
2   abc@gmail.com   11/10/18    02:11 PM
3   abc@gmail.com   11/10/18    03:14 PM
4   abc@gmail.com   11/11/18    06:16 AM
5   abc@gmail.com   11/11/18    09:10 AM
6   def@gmail.com   11/10/18    12:17 PM
7   def@gmail.com   11/10/18    03:24 PM
8   def@gmail.com   11/10/18    08:16 PM
9   def@gmail.com   11/10/18    09:13 PM
10  def@gmail.com   11/11/18    12:01 AM
```

I want to calculate the number of transactions made by each email ids within 4 hours. For example, email ids: abc@gmail.com made 3 transactions starting from 11/10/18 12.10 PM to 11/10/18 4.10 PM and made 2 transactions starting from 11/11/18 6.16 AM to 11/11/18 10.16 AM. email ids: def@gmail.com made 2 transactions starting from 11/10/18 12.17 PM to 11/10/18 4.17 PM and made 3 transactions starting from 11/10/18 8.16 PM to 11/11/18 12.16 AM.

My desired output is:

```
 email          hour interval                           purchase in 4 hours
abc@gmail.com   [11/10/18 12.10 PM to 11/10/18 4.10 PM] 3
abc@gmail.com   [11/11/18 6.16 AM to 11/11/18 10.16 AM] 2
def@gmail.com   [11/10/18 12.17 PM to 11/10/18 4.17 PM] 2
def@gmail.com   [11/10/18 8.16 PM to 11/11/18 12.16 AM] 3
```

I have done this for every hour. But I have no idea how to do this for specific time interval like 4 hours, 6 hours, 12 hours, etc. My dataset is having 500k rows. Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to create bins of 4 hour interval with `cut` after converting to `DateTime` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(email, grp = cut(mdy_hms(str_c(purchase, time_of_purchase)),
                breaks = '4 hour')) %>% 
   summarise(n = n())
```

---

If we need to divide from the first hour of each 'email'

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(datetime = mdy_hms(str_c(purchase, time_of_purchase))) %>%
    group_by(email) %>%
    group_by(grp = cut(datetime, breaks = seq(from =  min(datetime),
                       to = max(datetime),
                       by = "4 hour")),
           add = TRUE) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
```

Comment: Thank @akrun. But I am getting error: Error in inherits(breaks, "POSIXt") : 
  argument "breaks" is missing, with no default

Comment: @user3642360  Sorry, I meant `breaks` instead of `by`

Comment: But there is one problem, The above code is dividing the 24 hours like this: 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20. But I want to start calculating the time from the first date and time of transaction of a customer. for example, email ids: abc@gmail.com made 3 transactions starting from 11/10/18 12.10 PM to 11/10/18 4.10 PM and so on.

Comment: Thanks Akrun. It is taking a lot of time to run on my data. The data has 500k rows.

Comment: @user3642360  I made some changes.  Please check if that turns out faster

Comment: I am getting error something like this: Error: Column `grp` must be length 10 (the group size) or one, not 32

Comment: @user3642360  Okay  the error is due to the length difference.  You may pass the `seq` output as `breaks` in `cut`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. It is now working perfectly. Thanks a lot for your time and patience. :)